# In Google Reader, is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between show new items and show all items?

Tags: google-reader, keyboard-shortcuts

I pretty much use the keyboard exclusively in Google Reader, but I would really like a keyboard shortcut to switch between showing new items and all items.

I know about showing the shortcuts cheat sheet with `?`, but I am hoping maybe there is an undocumented shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing, so I tried userscripts.org and found [this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/65715), which seems to work fine on Firefox (well, Iceweasel 3.6.9).

Comment: Great find André. I had searched before I asked this question and couldn't find anything. I have installed this on FireFox and Chrome and used it successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. There is no such thing, at least by default.